Size grid rows intrinsically based off content

Row 1 should always be the height of its content + 1 share of the remaining available space
Row 2 should always be the height of its content
Row 3 should always be the height of its content + 2 shares of the remaining available space



.container{

  height: 150px;
  width: 75px;

  resize: vertical;
  overflow: auto;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr min-content 2fr;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;

  & :nth-child(1){
    background-color: pink;
  }
  & :nth-child(2){
    background-color: aqua;
  }
  & :nth-child(3){
    background-color: lime;
  }

}
<div class="container">

  <div>Row 1</div>
  <div>Row 2</div>
  <div>Row 3</div>

</div>



Row 2 works as I want, but Row 1 and Row 3 does not work as I want. If you resize the container and make it smaller, you will see that when Row 1 reaches its smallest height, Row 3 will be assigned all the remaining space. I don't want that to happen, but I always want this to be true:
Is what I want to achieve possible to achieve with CSS grid? And if so, how? In my mind, I want something like calc(min-content + 1fr) for Row 1, but that doesn't work
EDIT
Here's an example showing that Row 3 obtains all the remaining available space when Row 1 becomes its smallest size (at least for me, I don't know if the px unit might work differently depending on screen settings):


.container{

  height: 70px;
  width: 75px;

  resize: vertical;
  overflow: auto;

  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr min-content 2fr;
  grid-template-columns: 100%;

  & :nth-child(1){
    background-color: pink;
  }
  & :nth-child(2){
    background-color: aqua;
  }
  & :nth-child(3){
    background-color: lime;
  }

}
<div class="container">

  <div>Row 1</div>
  <div>Row 2</div>
  <div>Row 3</div>

</div>




"If you resize the container and make it smaller, you will see that when Row 1 reaches its smallest height, Row 3 will be assigned all the remaining space. I don't want that to happen, but I always want this to be true:" I can't reproduce this; what size are you setting? Are you sure you are not accidentally just changing the size of the container via dev tools (which does not recalculate grid row sizing)?

Grid layout is for fixed dimensions, if you want dynamic sizing based on unknown sizing it is better to use flexbox styling instead. The two layout methods can be used together!

@TylerH, I resize the container height using my mouse, but I have also updated the question with an example where the container has been set to a specific height that shows the problem for me. I hope it will show the problem for you as well.

@TylerH, I'm no CSS expert, especially not when it comes to flexbox and grid, but I have got the understanding that flexbox has been designed for one dimensional data, while grid has been designed for two dimensional data. From that perspective I don't understand Grid layout is for fixed dimensions, if you want dynamic sizing based on unknown sizing it is better to use flexbox styling instead. Why should flexbox be better/more powerful at sizing in one direction than grid? But perhaps the answer to that is way too complicated for me ^^'

Perhaps I should have specified that grid layout is for fixed layouts where you know exactly where one region should end and another should begin, though within those regions you could have flexible amounts of rows/columns. For maximum flexibility (no pun intended) when using grid layout, it's recommended to create the grid layout "framework" you want and then use flex layout within the grid for the rows and columns. Although if you're working with one-dimensional content like in this example, you don't need grid layout; flexbox alone works perfectly.

Better to work with flexbox than with an explicit grid if you want size to be based on height of content:


.container {
  min-height: 150px;
  width: 75px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  & :nth-child(1) {
    background-color: pink;
    flex-grow: 1;
  }
  & :nth-child(2) {
    background-color: aqua;
  }
  & :nth-child(3) {
    background-color: lime;
    flex-grow: 2;
  }
}
<div class="container">
  <div>Row 1</div>
  <div>Row 2</div>
  <div>Row 3</div>
</div>



Flex algorithm will try and fit everything based off content size, and then the remaining available space will be filled at the rates described by flex-grow

You need 6 rows with corresponding grid-rows in the children


.container{

  height: 150px;
  width: 75px;

  resize: vertical;
  overflow: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows:repeat(2, 1fr) min-content repeat(3, 1fr);

  & :nth-child(1){
    background-color: pink;
    grid-row:span 2;
  }
  & :nth-child(2){
    background-color: aqua;
  }
  & :nth-child(3){
    background-color: lime;
    grid-row:span 3;
  }

}
<div class="container">

  <div>Row 1</div>
  <div>Row 2</div>
  <div>Row 3</div>

</div>




Thanks for the suggestion, but this does unfortunately not work preciously the way I want it to. If you make the height of the container smaller, you'll see that Row 1 and Row 3 becomes smaller than their content. I need the container to become scrollable instead, as in the code example in my question. Do you know if that's possible to achieve?
